# Hexadecimal to Decimal Pascal Error Illegal Expression using Dev-Pascal

Tags: pascal

I am creating a program that converts hexadecimal number to decimal number. Here is the code :

```
program hexadesimal;
uses crt;
var
d, j, l, pow, y:integer;
x:longint;
h:string;
label z;
begin
z:
readln(h);
d:=0;
l:=length(h);
for j:=1 to length(h) do
begin
if (h[j] = 'A') then h[j] = '10';
if (h[j] = 'B') then h[j] = '11';
if (h[j] = 'C') then h[j] = '12';
if (h[j] = 'D') then h[j] = '13';
if (h[j] = 'E') then h[j] = '14';
if (h[j] = 'F') then h[j] = '15';
l:=l - 1;
pow := power(16, l);
val(h[j], x, y);
d := d + (x * pow);
end;
writeln(d);
readln;
end.
```

However, when I compiled, an error appeared illegal expression and it points at these lines :

```
if (h[j] = 'A') then h[j] = '10';
if (h[j] = 'B') then h[j] = '11';
if (h[j] = 'C') then h[j] = '12';
if (h[j] = 'D') then h[j] = '13';
if (h[j] = 'E') then h[j] = '14';
if (h[j] = 'F') then h[j] = '15';
```

What should I do ?

Comment: can you show the full error??

Comment: Error : Illegal Expression (6 lines), There are 6 errors compiling module, stopping @ManojSalvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines `if (h[j] = 'A') then h[j] = '10';` do not have sense. `h[j]` refers to a character within the string and so it can not be equal to a string (containing 2 or mor characters) like '10'. If you wish to assign the value to a variable you need use `:=` operator. `h[j] = '10'` is not an assignmet, but a comparison operator, that ever results in `FALSE` in your case. In other words you get the following structure: `if (TRUE/FALSE) then FALSE;`